# In this selection sort code i get from {8,3,5,9,2} an array answer of{2,3,3,5}

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, selection-sort

I don't understand where is the problem , I traced it and i get the correct sorting , or if its something wrong with keeping up with the values can someone tell me where exactly , referring to my code trial why it resulted in this answer .

```
package sorting;
public class soring {
    public static void selectionsort(int [] a ) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            int minindex = i; 
            int min = a[minindex];
            for(int j=i+1; j<a.length; j++) {
                if(min>a[j]) 
                    min = a[j];
                minindex = j;
            }
            a[minindex]=a[i];
            a[i]=min;
        }
    }

    public static void display (int []a) {
        for (int i =0 ; i<a.length-1 ;i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] a = {8,3,5,9,2};
        soring.selectionsort(a);
        soring.display(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody can understand what the actual question is.

Comment: a selection sort method , I mentioned it in the header question , an array of {8,3,5,2} being sorted by selectionsort .

Comment: Ask your IDE to indent your code, and you'll find the problem immediately. **Always** use curly braces around your blocks (after if, for, while, etc.). using the debugger to step through the code helps, too.

Comment: Yes will do for the curly brackets ,but how do I indent my code ? @JBNizet

Comment: @Mayar it depends on your IDE. But whether it's Eclipse, IntelliJ or NetBeans, googlinf for "how to indent code in [your IDE]" gives the answer. Google is your friend. All IDEs also have a command allowing to search for commands.

Comment: That's really helpful , okay will do , thank you @JBNizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem:

```
for (int i =0 ; i<a.length-1 ;i++) {
   System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

In your `display()` method you're looping until less that the length minus one, which will not display the last value. Change this to `i<a.length`

And again in your `selectionsort()` method you loop so that the last element is never touched. Second, you are missing brackets around one of your `if` statements. This is making it so that the line `minindex = j;` is not inside the `if` block and is therefore always executed. Change:

```
if(min>a[j]) 
   min = a[j];
   minindex = j ;
```

To:

```
if(min>a[j]) {
     min = a[j];
     minindex = j ;
 }
```

Comment: Yes that worked out ! , and now its clear for me thank you